# Making classified grid from tab using MapInfo

Tags: raster, mapinfo

I have a Tab file in MapInfo and values are text (Server Name). I want to create a classified grid. The file has more than 1 million points.

Lat---Long----ServerID

Anyone has created a classified grid in MapInfo Pro?

---

I created the points and try the Voronoi (table) (under Regions>Voronoi (table)), for the data aggregation I used "ServerID" note that Server ID is a string and several points have the same ServerID
[image]

Comment: Make sure that you are creating an Extended Native table for your Voronoi polygons

Answer (score 0):

One method is to convert your point data into a Voronoi dataset dividing the area between the points. Then you can use the Rasterize option in MapInfo Pro Advanced to convert your Voronoi polygons into raster.

Note that the Rasterize method assigns the color from the polygons to the classified grid. That's why most of the rasters in my example below are all white and only a few have been assigned a color.

[image]

Comment: CSV sheet has more than 25 million points, and every time MAPINFO Crashed

Comment: Make sure you use an Extended Tab file. You can configure this under System Preferences I'm assuming you are using a 64-bit version of MapInfo Pro?